# Google Apps API: Non-destructive check for calendar subscription

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a command line script to subscribe every account on our Google domain (Apps for Education and Business) to a single academic schedule calendar. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to force this, so I'm using Calendar API V2 and the python API client to grab all the accounts and individually subscribe them to the calendar. The API responds differently depending on whether the user was already subscribed to the calendar, however the documentation doesn't seem to indicate any way to check whether someone is already subscribed to a calendar without changing the state of the subscription.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_python#ManagingSubscriptions

I need a non-destructive way to find out who is already subscribed to the calendar so we can make a list and roll-back should we decide to cancel this whole calendar endeavour.

Right now the best way I can think of doing this is to do perform the change and record which ones were already subscribed, but I'd really rather see if theres a side-effect free way of doing this before I unleash it on the production domain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a list of all the calendars in a user's list. Note that this includes hidden calendars that the user will not see in their UI:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_python#RetrievingCalendars

feed = calendar_client.GetAllCalendarsFeed()
print feed.title.text
for i, a_calendar in enumerate(feed.entry):
  print '\t%s. %s' % (i, a_calendar.title.text,)